# AvPlayer seekToTime issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, avplayer

I am working on video app and playing video on `AVPlayer`. But problem is when I seek the video to particular time with the help of `UISlider`. The player `seekToTime` method get time value in `integer` but I want that it gets in `float`. Please help
Here is my code

```
Float32 sliderValue = (float) avPlayerSlider.value;
[mPlayer seekToTime:CMTimeMake(sliderValue, 1) toleranceBefore:kCMTimeZero toleranceAfter:kCMTimeZero];
```

Answer (score 3):

You can set proper time scale.

```
CMTimeMake(12345, 10000); //This is 1.2345 seconds
```

Or use defined time scales

```
#define NSEC_PER_USEC   1000ull     /* nanoseconds per microsecond */
#define USEC_PER_SEC    1000000ull  /* microseconds per second */
#define NSEC_PER_SEC    1000000000ull   /* nanoseconds per second */
#define NSEC_PER_MSEC   1000000ull  /* nanoseconds per millisecond */
```

In my player app, I'm using such conversations:

```
CMTime thumbTime = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(self.currentPlaybackTime, NSEC_PER_SEC);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have also been plagued by this problem, fix it and the code below:

```
[_playerItem cancelPendingSeeks];
[_player seekToTime:CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(leftPosition, NSEC_PER_SEC) toleranceBefore:kCMTimeZero toleranceAfter:kCMTimeZero];
```

leftPosition(CGFloat) is the time of the asset, the unit is a second.

I hope can help to you